# Headset amplifier (headphone amplifier with mic preamp)

Tags: microphone, headphones, amplifier, m-audio, rca

I have and m-audio 24/96 soundcard with one RCA-out and one RCA-in pair. I want to connect a headphone with a separate mic (modmic) to this audio card.

Now I need a nice headphone amplifier I get that much, but I also want a (at least OK) mic pre-amp in order for my modmic microphone to be connected to the sound card. I do need a mic pre-amp, right?

I have been looking for a product that has both these features but I can't find any. Does anyone know a good way to connect my equipment to my soundcard in my PC? It shouldn't cost a fortune and shouldn't be too clumsy like a full-featured mixerboard or anything. Best thing would be if it could fit somehow inside my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you just plug it into the mic-input on the motherboard?

Comment: Because the motherboard sound-card is crap, so I'd rather not. But I guess mic sound is not equally important on the other hand. I would also like to have both sound in and sound out on the same soundcard as i suspect there could be trouble sometimes, although not sure.

Comment: I think by trying to go down this route you are trying to make life difficult for yourself. You will find that the motherboard sound is pretty good for most applications and will be perfectly adequate to handle the modmic.

Comment: OK. Great input. I suppose you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The M-audio 24/96 soundcard is not designed to do what you are asking. If you wanted a simple, single-piece solution for handling mic input and headphone output, you could look at a small external mixer with USB interface to the computer.

The Modmic is a cheap electret mic capsule with a 3.5mm plug designed to connect to the (pink) mic input connector on a computer.  There are no commercially-available mic preamps that use 3.5mm input jacks because if you are using a cheap "computer mic" with a 3.5mm plug, then you have chosen the "cheap and dirty" realm of computer mic input, not something that requires an external mic preamp.

We don't know what your application is, so we don't know why you think you need a "nice headphone amplifier" or an external mic preamp?  If you are attempting to record high-quality voice tracks, then you are using rather down-scale microphone. But if you are only doing a Skype call or recording a podcast, etc. there probably isn't anything wrong with what you already have.